# Pandas Dataframe Multiindex Merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multi-index

I wanted to ask a questions regarding merging multiindex dataframe in pandas, here is a hypothetical scenario:

```py
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['third', 'fourth'])

s1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8), index=index1, columns=['s1'])
s2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8), index=index2, columns=['s2'])
```

Then either

```py
s1.merge(s2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

or

```py
s1.merge(s2, how='left', left_on=['first', 'second'], right_on=['third', 'fourth'])
```

will result in error.

Do I have to do `reset_index()` on either `s1`/`s2` to make this work?

Comment: This is one of the things that frustrates many new pandas users/coders, there are so many different ways to do the same thing.   I like that, because depending on the dataset or why are you doing it in the first place, you can go the easy to code and understand route or you can optimize for quicker run times route.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Seems like you need to use a combination of them.

```
s1.merge(s2, left_index=True, right_on=['third', 'fourth'])
#s1.merge(s2, right_index=True, left_on=['first', 'second'])
```

#### Output:

```
               s1        s2
bar one  0.765385 -0.365508
    two  1.462860  0.751862
baz one  0.304163  0.761663
    two -0.816658 -1.810634
foo one  1.891434  1.450081
    two  0.571294  1.116862
qux one  1.056516 -0.052927
    two -0.574916 -1.197596
```

Comment: Why not `right_on=s2.index.names`?

Answer (score 9):

Other than using the indexes names as pointed by @ALollz, you can simply use `loc`, which will match indexes automatically

```
s1.loc[:, 's2'] = s2   # Or explicitly, s2['s2']

                s1           s2
first   second      
bar     one     -0.111384   -2.341803
        two     -1.226569    1.308240
baz     one      1.880835    0.697946
        two     -0.008979   -0.247896
foo     one      0.103864   -1.039990
        two      0.836931    0.000811
qux     one     -0.859005   -1.199615
        two     -0.321341   -1.098691
```

A general formula would be

```
s1.loc[:, s2.columns] = s2
```

Answer (score 8):

Assign it by `combine_first`

```
s1.combine_first(s2)
Out[19]: 
                    s1        s2
first second                    
bar   one     0.039203  0.795963
      two     0.454782 -0.222806
baz   one     3.101120 -0.645474
      two    -1.174929 -0.875561
foo   one    -0.887226  1.078218
      two     1.507546 -1.078564
qux   one     0.028048  0.042462
      two     0.826544 -0.375351

# s2.combine_first(s1)
```

Answer (score 6):

#### `rename_axis`

You can rename the index levels of one and let `join` do its thing

```
s1.join(s2.rename_axis(s1.index.names))

                    s1        s2
first second                    
bar   one    -0.696420 -1.040463
      two     0.640891  1.483262
baz   one     1.598837  0.097424
      two     0.003994 -0.948419
foo   one    -0.717401  1.190019
      two    -1.201237 -0.000738
qux   one     0.559684 -0.505640
      two     1.979700  0.186013
```

---

#### `concat`

```
pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)

                    s1        s2
first second                    
bar   one    -0.696420 -1.040463
      two     0.640891  1.483262
baz   one     1.598837  0.097424
      two     0.003994 -0.948419
foo   one    -0.717401  1.190019
      two    -1.201237 -0.000738
qux   one     0.559684 -0.505640
      two     1.979700  0.186013
```