# Joining two multi-index dataframes with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two multi-index dataframes which should have the same index names (barring any format issues) that I want to join together.

DF1 =

[image]

DF2 =

[image]

I want to join DF2 to DF1 only where the NAME and code match so on this dataframe for example, it would pull in qty for 10'' of 69.0

I've tried different variations of join, concat and multiindex.join but can't see to figure it out.  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: See [Pandas DataFrame Multiindex Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785579/pandas-dataframe-multiindex-merge), which gives many options for how to join them.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,how='left',on=['NAME','code'])`