# Full outer join on two multiindex dataframes (one with multi level columns) not working properly pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python 3.8, pandas 1.1.2

I have two dateframes with multiindex

df1 (multi level column):

```
                       user      price
                       count     sum
name    date    hour 
  A      9/17    1       33       34
  A      9/17    2       66       55
  A      9/17    3       77       2
  A      9/17    4       88       1
```

df2:

```
                       seller_count
name    date    hour 
  A      9/17    1        100 
  A      9/17    15        66
```

I am trying to do full outer join on two of them.

Desired output:

```
                       user      price
                       count     sum        seller_count
name    date    hour 
  A      9/17    1       33       34            100
  A      9/17    2       66       55            null
  A      9/17    3       77       2             null
  A      9/17    4       88       1             null
  A      9/17    15     Null     Null           66
```

I am trying to find out a way to do this without resetting indexes. Any help? Thanks!

solution from [Pandas Dataframe Multiindex Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785579/pandas-dataframe-multiindex-merge) does not seem to work, I am only able to get `seller_count` if it has same `name, date,hour` as df1.

df1.columns outputs:

```
MultiIndex([(          'user',    'count'),
            (           'price',    'sum')])
```

df2.columns outputs:

```
Index(["seller_count"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**:

```
print (df1.index)
MultiIndex([('A', '9/17', 1),
            ('A', '9/17', 2),
            ('A', '9/17', 3),
            ('A', '9/17', 4)],
           names=['name', 'date', 'hour'])

print (df1.columns)
MultiIndex([( 'user', 'count'),
            ('price',   'sum')],
           )

print (df2.index)
MultiIndex([('A', '9/17',  1),
            ('A', '9/17', 15)],
           names=['name', 'date', 'hour'])

print (df2.columns)
Index(['seller_count'], dtype='object')
```

First is necessary create `MultiIndex` in `df2`, then use merge with `outer join`:

```
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[''], df2.columns])

print (df2.columns)
MultiIndex([('', 'seller_count')],
           )

df = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer")
print (df)
                user price             
               count   sum seller_count
name date hour                         
A    9/17 1     33.0  34.0        100.0
          2     66.0  55.0          NaN
          3     77.0   2.0          NaN
          4     88.0   1.0          NaN
          15     NaN   NaN         66.0
```

---

```
df = df1.join(df2, how="outer")
print (df)
                user price             
               count   sum seller_count
name date hour                         
A    9/17 1     33.0  34.0        100.0
          2     66.0  55.0          NaN
          3     77.0   2.0          NaN
          4     88.0   1.0          NaN
          15     NaN   NaN         66.0
```

---

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([( 'user',        'count'),
            ('price',          'sum'),
            (     '', 'seller_count')],
           )


print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('A', '9/17',  1),
            ('A', '9/17',  2),
            ('A', '9/17',  3),
            ('A', '9/17',  4),
            ('A', '9/17', 15)],
           names=['name', 'date', 'hour'])
```

Comment: df2 is already a multiindex, it has been created by using groupby.agg on three columns. I didn't make myself clear, updated my question.

Comment: @Ambleu - What is `print (df1.columns)` and `print (df2.columns)` ?

Comment: Ah, I see that would make it more clear.  Will update.

Comment: @Ambleu - Added setup for see index and columns of input data.

Comment: hm... wait I don't get why df2 is single index? I did groupby on 3 columns

Comment: @Ambleu - No, it is Multiindex too. For both DataFrames. There are 3 times MultiIndex and 1 time single index for `df2.columns`

Comment: Thank you so much! I still don't quite understand `There are 3 times MultiIndex and 1 time single index` this part though. Am guessing this is the reason I am converting df2.columns

Comment: @Ambleu - I describe setup part of my solution. ;)

Comment: Ah didn't understand it before but now I get it! Really appreciate your help this code is simple and does the job perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that column names in the index in *df1* are of "single level".
You can achieve it the following way:

1. The source file contains:

   ```
   name,date,hour,user,price
    , , ,count,sum
   A,9/17,1,33,34
   A,9/17,2,66,55
   A,9/17,3,77,2
   A,9/17,4,88,1
   ```

   Note spaces as first 3 column names at the second level.
2. Read the file executing:

   ```
   df1 = pd.read_csv('Input_1.csv', header=[0,1])
   df1 = df1.set_index([('name', ' '), ('date', ' '), ('hour', ' ')])\
       .rename_axis(index=['name', 'date', 'hour'])
   ```

This way "2-level" column names, after setting as the index, get **single**
level names.

Another detail to note is that:

- index column names in both DataFrames are of **single** level,
- *df1* has a **MultiIndex** on columns,
- *df2* has an **ordinary** (single level) index on columns,
- the result should have **MultiIndex** on columns.

To perform the join, you have to start from adding a MultiIndex level
to the column index in *df2* (with a space as the top level):

```
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[' '], df2.columns])
```

Then perform ordinary outer join:

```
result = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

The result is:

```
                user price             
               count   sum seller_count
name date hour                         
A    9/17 1     33.0  34.0        100.0
          2     66.0  55.0          NaN
          3     77.0   2.0          NaN
          4     88.0   1.0          NaN
          15     NaN   NaN         66.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. df1 is multiindex with multi level columns and df2 is multiindex. I've updated my question.

Comment: I see that your both DataFrames have a MultiIndex on **rows**. But as far as **columns** are concerned: 1. *df1* has a **MultiIndex** on columns. 2. *df2* has an **ordinary** (single level) index on columns. This is why my code adds a level of the **column** index in *df2*.